# Parsing .wab Microsoft Outlook Address Book files in java

Tags: java, parsing, outlook

I am attempting to parse .wab files using java. Upon inspection the files look encoded because when you open them in note it just looks like garbage. The only way I have found to parse this data is to actually import it using Microsoft Outlook.

Is there an API that can be used in java to parse out this data? Or does anyone know how to go about parsing a .wab file?

Answer (score 0):

Using COM from Java in combination with this free (LGPL) component http://www.nektra.com/products/nktwab-outlook-express-windows-mail-wab-api/ should allow for doing what you ask...

Another option is to use libwab from Java - see http://www.filewut.com/spages/page.php/software/libwab